# How to write a data loading transaction in DB2?

Tags: transactions, db2

I have a staging table from where I want to upsert (merge into) the data to it's corresponding main table. What I want to achieve is to make sure I can insert all the rows without errors, once it is done then commit the changes and drop the staging table (if dropping the table is possible in the same statement). If there is an error, I want to make sure that nothing has loaded to the main table, and if it is possible, I also want to delete the staging table.

I was looking for a clear guide to this but I haven't found any.
What is the correct syntax for this in DB2?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Comment: its an ibm cloud db2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing multiple things, it would be better to accomplish them in a stored procedure. Usually, I include an output parameter to indicate if any exception occurred in the proc.